# Why does my web scraper continue to ignore a very obvious tag

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the list of all the presidents that have won the US election from [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_presidential_election) site. The table is fairly large so I have to write a substantial amount of code to extract the names of  ONLY the Presidents that won the elections.

Note: I am not interested in the vice presidents.

For the first 5 elections, the tags holding the name victorious presidents and the elected vice presidents are quite similar, so I tried to use the `<sup>` tag to differentiate them.

Here is a snippet of the code:

```
winners_list=list()
for row in rows:
    winner_cheek=row.find_all('td')
    pick_president=list()
    for p in winner_cheek:
            try:
                if p.find('sup')==True:
                    print(p.find('sup'))
                    continue
                else:
                    winner= p.find('b').get_text()
                    print(winner)
                    pick_president.append(winner)
             except:continue
    if len(pick_president)>0: 
        winners_list.append(pick_president[0])
print(len(winners_list))
```

when I run the code, my web scraper behaves as if the following lines does not exist, it completely ignores then am just returns the vice presidents anyway.

```
if p.find('sup')==True:
    print(p.find('sup'))
    continue
```

I think there is something i am not doing right, but i can not figure what that is yet.
can someone help me?

here is a screenshot of the page[image]

Comment: Note, I encounter the same problem when I try to scrape the results of the electoral votes. The scraper behaves as if the code is not there, and just ignores it completely.

Comment: maybe show a screenshot of what your scrapping on the page?

Comment: @coderoftheday You mean a screen shot of the table?

Comment: yes, because i cant find ```'sup'```

Comment: @coderofthedayi have added the screnshot

Comment: see how to produce a [mcve]

Comment: How are the elected presidents defined? all of them that are under the `Presidential candidate` column which are not bold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works perfectly fine?

```
import requests
import bs4

urlsite = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_presidential_election#Popular_vote')
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(urlsite.content, 'lxml')


winners_list=list()
winner_cheek=soup.find_all('td')
pick_president=list()
for p in winner_cheek:
    try:
        if p.find('sup'):
            print(p.find('sup'))
            print('\n\nIts not ignoring\n\n')
            continue
        else:
            winner= p.find('b').get_text()
            print(winner)
            pick_president.append(winner)
    except:continue
if len(pick_president)>0:
    winners_list.append(pick_president[0])
print(len(winners_list))
```

I added `print('\n\nIts not ignoring\n\n')`
to show you, its not ignoring

Comment: do you have to use wikipedia?